# Executing JavaScript in pure Python environment

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I want to run existing simple (no special tricks) JavaScript code (several thousand lines) in a pure Python environment (Google AppEngine).

The code runs fine with PyV8 (but it is not pure Python).

Is PyJON mature enough for this?

Can I define custom objects in Python and use them in JavaScript (like in PyV8)?

Comment: I'm not aware on any Python library that does that. I would probably setup some external service (aws?) with an API to do that. Your code can call the api and get the result.

Comment: The only way to know if PyJON is mature enough is to give it a try.  And if that doesn't work, lazy1 has a good suggestion.

Comment: @lazy1: This (AWS) was the original idea. But the system would be much simpler, if the JavaScript could be run on the AppEngine backends, where the data store can be accessed  and where someone else is responsible for the system wnbironment.

Comment: @Theron: OK, I will do just this. I have already implemented my first Python object and I am able to access it from JavaScript. It is a bit different from PyV8, but i seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com), where you can access you datastore objects in JSON format.